# Bubble Sort Simulation JButton coloring

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, bubble-sort

Im trying to make a program that will help visualize the bubble sort algorithm. The script sorts the array correctly, however it does not allow the `JFrame` to open until it has finished. Is there a way to make it recolor all of the buttons before moving ahead with its sorting? Posted below is the class that handles the sorting and coloring currently.

```java
public class SortStart {

    private JButton[] list;
    private int[] randomList;

    public SortStart(JButton[] list, int[] randomList){
        this.list = list;
        this.randomList = randomList;
    }

    public void run(){

        String str = "";
        int temp = 0;
        int k = 0;
        boolean swapped = true;

        //Sort the colors
        while(swapped){
            swapped = false;
            k ++;
            for(int i = 0; i < randomList.length - k; i ++){
                if(randomList[i] > randomList[i+1]){
                    temp = randomList[i];
                    randomList[i] = randomList[i+1];
                    randomList[i+1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    for(int l = 0; l < randomList.length; l++){
                        System.out.print(randomList[l] + ", ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int j = 0; j < randomList.length; j++){
                        list[j].setBackground(new java.awt.Color(randomList[j],randomList[j],255)); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think background thread. Think SwingWorker. Search on this for the details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SwingWorker can execute only once, instead make an instance of a Thread with a Runnable class using a PropertyChangeListener to reflect the changes in the view.
You're using the view's thread to run your code so nothing else can execute (repaints) until finished.
In your Runnable class you should define a PropertyChangeSupport object bound to the object been modified. And add the method addPropertyChangeListener (then define a PropertyChangeListener in your view), something like this:

```
private PropertyChangeSupport mPcs =
    new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

public void setMouthWidth(int mw) {
    int oldMouthWidth = mMouthWidth;
    mMouthWidth = mw;
    mPcs.firePropertyChange("mouthWidth", oldMouthWidth, mw); //the modification is "published"
}

public void
addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    mPcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void
removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    mPcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: I kind of see what you are getting at, but unfortunatley I have no experience using threads (im a beginning java student) so I am still a bit lost on what you are actually describing.

Comment: You create a Thread using a class that implement the Runnable interface, this interface has a method called run() that's where you put the code or the call to execute. Once created the thread you need to call the start() method to run the Runnable :D. Thread t = new Thread(Runnable) --> then --> t.start()

Comment: So you're saying I could put in code in the run method that colors the  buttons? Or would that be where I put the script for sorting it?

Comment: The coloring is made in the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) witch is the "view" thread, You should run the sort in the run() method.